# Is it possible to create a new folder and then export R data to this folder?

Tags: r

Initially, I have the following code

```
path="M:/MainFiles/"
Index="Columbus"
write.csv(data,paste(paste(paste(path,Index, sep = ""), Sys.Date(), sep = "_" ), ".csv", sep = ""))
```

This file is saved to
`"M:/MainFiles/Columbus_2021-01-21.csv"`

I want that the file is saved to `"M:/MainFiles/2021-01-21/Columbus_2021-01-21.csv"` , where 2021-01-21 is `Sys.date()`. As a result, every ay a new folder is created and the file is saved to this folder.

Comment: You could replace your current code with `paste0(path, Index, "_", Sys.Date(), ".csv")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `file.path` to create path/file names in a OS independent way, and `dir.create` to create a new directory, if it doesn't exist yet.

```
path <- "M:/MainFiles"
Index <- "Columbus"

newday <- file.path(path, Sys.Date())
newday
#[1] "M:/MainFiles/2021-01-21"

if(!dir.exists(newday)){
  dir.create(newday)
}
filename <- paste0(paste(Index, Sys.Date(), sep = "_"), ".csv")
filename <- file.path(newday, filename)
filename
#[1] "M:/MainFiles/2021-01-21/Columbus_2021-01-21.csv"
```

This can be written as a function.

```
newDayCreate <- function(path, index){
  newdir <- file.path(path, Sys.Date())
  yes <- dir.create(newdir)
  filename <- paste0(paste(index, Sys.Date(), sep = "_"), ".csv")
  filename <- file.path(newdir, filename)
  list(dir.create = yes, 
       newdir = newdir, 
       filename = filename)
}

newDayCreate("~/tmp", Index)
#$dir.create
#[1] TRUE
#
#$newdir
#[1] "~/tmp/2021-01-21"
#
#$filename
#[1] "~/tmp/2021-01-21/Columbus_2021-01-21.csv"
```

Note that the new directory was created, but the file was not written to disk. The function's value must be assigned to a variable and the list member `filename` used in `write.csv`:

```
res <- newDayCreate("~/tmp", Index)
#Warning message:  
#In dir.create(newdir) : '/<omited>/tmp/2021-01-21' already exists
```

The warning says that I had previously created the directory (in the previous instruction above).
Now see what is in `res`:

```
res
#$dir.create
#[1] FALSE
#
#$newdir
#[1] "~/tmp/2021-01-21"
#
#$filename
#[1] "~/tmp/2021-01-21/Columbus_2021-01-21.csv"
```

The result `res$dir.create` is `FALSE`. In order to write the file to disk, use

```
write.csv(data, res$filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
path <- "M:/MainFiles/"
FROMDATE <- sys.date()
dir.create(paste0(path,FROMDATE,sep = ""))
qq <- paste0(path,FROMDATE) 
setwd(qq)
write.csv(data,'data.csv',rows.name=F)
```